# How to obtain the user model's attributes in Laravel via class accessor

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, eloquent, accessor

I am trying to create a customer at the same time as a user is created in the RegisterController (**part of the Laravel Auth package**), if that user registers as a customer. However, I have tried adding an 'accessor' to the User class by adding the following code to my User model, to access the user_id property, but the accessor does not seem to work as intended. (SEE: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor)

```
public function getUserIdAttribute($user_id)
{
    return $user_id;
}
```

Then I try to access it directly from the model in the RegisterController with this function:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{

    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'username' => $data['username'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'utype' => $data['utype'],
    ]);

    if ($data['utype'] == "customer") {
        Customer::create([
            'user_id' => $user->user_id,
        ]);
    }

    return $user;
}
```

For some reason, the `$user->user_id` returns NULL though. What is the issue? Why is the accessor not being applied properly?

Comment: is the primary key for the 'users' table 'user_id'?

Comment: @lagbox Thank you ! That was my issue, the primary key was actually just 'id' .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @lagbox, I figured out what the issue was. Turns out, the column name was simply 'id'.

Comment: More important, if you have relation between `User` and `Customer` models (which you should), then good practice of registration of `$customer` entity would go as simple as `$user->customer()->create();`. Also, check [observers](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#observers) since those are great place to put this proposed line of mine.

Comment: @Tpojka Thanks for the suggestion! I'll definitely implement in that in our model!